# can anyone explain to me why the strategy.entry function is not executed?

Tags: pine-script

can anyone explain to me why the strategy.entry function is not executed? This is intended to be a pine script that buys an asset every other week and tracks the accumulation of that asset. I have the following script that doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't enter any trades or actually save the accumulation variable. The accumulation variable switches between 0 and 1, it doesn't incrementally increase.

```
// This strategy buys the asset displayed on the active chart every 
other week.
strategy("Dollar Cost Averaging")

// Set the amount of USD to buy the asset.
investment_amount = 75

// Variable to track accumulation.
float accumulation = 0

// Buy the asset every other week.
if (weekofyear(time) % 2 == 1.0) and (dayofweek(time) == 2.0) and 
(hour(time) == 12.0) and (minute(time) == 0.0)

    // Buy.
    strategy.entry(id = "Buy", direction = strategy.long, 
    qty=float(investment_amount/close))

    // Alternative way of keeping track of the accumulation.
    accumulation += float(investment_amount/close)
```

I tried looking up simple DCA pine scripts, but I only found scripts that bought based on indicators. I just want to buy every 2 weeks.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: Should I have written "Why doesn't this script execute the entry?"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the version 5 of pinescript.
The to declare a float, you must use the value = 0.0 , not = 0.
Then you must use 'var' to declare and give a value the first time only. In your code you use :

```
float accumulation = 0
```

which reset the value of accumulation to 0 each new bar

Here is the code :

```
//@version=5
strategy("Dollar Cost Averaging")

// Set the amount of USD to buy the asset.
investment_amount = 75.0

// Variable to track accumulation.
var accumulation = 0.0

// Buy the asset every other week.
weektoinvest = (weekofyear(time) % 2 == 1) and (dayofweek(time) == 2) and (hour(time) == 12) and (minute(time) == 0)
if weektoinvest
    // Buy.
    strategy.entry(id = "Buy", direction = strategy.long, qty= investment_amount/close)

    // Alternative way of keeping track of the accumulation.
    accumulation += investment_amount/close
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. The accumulation variable stays at 0 and I still don't see the entries on the chart or in the strategy tester. Is there a setting somewhere I might be missing?

Comment: I solved the problem by only using (weekofyear(time) % 2 == 1). It works as expected.

Comment: @B3ntley this code works, I tested it. you need to use an hour timeframe to see accumulation grows as you were looking for hour=12. I also corrected a lot of error in your original code as the correct use of the float variable. Thanks to accept my answer. Post your own answer with my corrections isn’t fair.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the timeframe must be what is currently viewed. I was thinking that data was always available, just not being displayed. I assumed the answer was not complete. While you did correct the error for my accumulation variable (I appreciate that), the pyramiding variable needed to be set to a higher value otherwise only 1 entry would be made.

Comment: @B3ntley in StackOverFlow the goal is to help people. People who find help accept the answer when help is provided. In instance your question was 'why the strategy.entry function is not executed'. You didn't accept the answer is not fair and not helping other.